# How can I modify the size of my TextButton so that it is equal to it's child Text widget's height in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating an App Login page using Flutter framework and I want the the `TextButton` as well as the "Forgot password?" text to be horizontally aligned in the screen, but the following code displays the button below the "Forgot Password?" text. I tried modifying the button's height and width parameters as well as modifying the spacing in the `Wrap` widget but I still didn't get the expected outcome. Wrapping the `TextButton` with `SizedBox` widget too didn't worked as it hid the button from the screen. Is there any other way to get the desired outcome?
[Part of the screen where the `TextButton` and "Forgot password?" text is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdyUh.png)

```dart
   Wrap(
      children: [
        Text(
          "Forgot password?",
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0,
          ),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(
            "Click here",
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16.0,
              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to Align your two buttons horizontally, just wrap them with a Row widget, userSizedbox to adjust space between them, and if necessary wrap the Row with Padding to adjust the location of buttons like;

```
   Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
     child: Row(
        children: [
          Text(
            "Forgot password?",
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10,),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              "Click here",
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16.0,
                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
   ),
```

Comment: Yes, this solved my issue, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to below code hope its helpful to you. Wrap your Text and TextButton widget inside Row().

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Forgot password?",
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                //Write here your onPressed function call
                print('Button Pressed!');
              },
              child: Text(
                "Click here",
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Your Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it worked perfectly but I did not wanted that much space to be left between the button and the text as it would have looked a bit awkward in my opinion...

Comment: Ok just remove `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,` from row

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach to overcome this with `RichText`, `TextSpan` and `TapGestureRecognizer`.

To use `TapGestureRecognizer`, you will have to import `'package:flutter/gestures.dart'`

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: "Forgot password? ",
    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16.0,
    ),
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: "Click here",
        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0,
          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
        ),
        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
          ..onTap = () => {},
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

You can use this instead of using a TextButton.

Result is as below.
[image: result image]

Comment: Thanks alot for this suggestion, but I was looking for a method in which I didn't had to import any additional packages, although I will keep this method in mind for any future projects.